# cscope and ctag cannot find a function definition which is located in class declaration

Tags: function, lookup, definition, cscope

I use vim + ctag + cscope when I browse C++ source code.
When I want to look up a definition of any function cscope and/or ctag produce a list of cadidates which seem to be the one.

But when I try this for a function which is defined in a class declaration in a header file, none of those two produce the list of cadidates.
When ctag and/or cscope fail like this I now know that the function definition should be in a header file. So I open the header file and find the function definition in it.

But I wonder if this is inevitable behavior of ctag and cscope.
Aren't there any way to make them(ctag and cscope) clever for this kind of cases so that I can find the definition of every function even though they are defined in a header file?

Thank you very much.

Journeyer J. Joh

Answer (score 1):

I generated tag file like the one below.

```
ctags --langmap=C++:.inc --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+fq --sort=foldcase -R .
```

But it has to be corrected the way below.

```
ctags --langmap=C++:+.inc --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+fq --sort=foldcase -R .
```

from

```
--langmap=C++:.inc
```

to

```
--langmap=C++:+.inc
```

[`man ctags`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ctags) has instruction for this:

> [...] to specify that only files with extensions of .c and .x are to be treated as C language files, use "--langmap=c:.c.x"; to also add files with extensions of .j as Java language files, specify "--langmap=c:.c.x,java:+.j".